# Is there an API for Safari Reader?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, safari

Does Safari Reader have an API which one can use to filter the text from a webpage (cleans adverts, unneeded parts of text etc.) for an iOS app?

If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just was doing some research for my app, heres what I've found. couldn't post all the links cause I'm new, but easily googleable

Read, Clear Read API: http://readapp.net/pub.html

Instapaper itself. Simple and Full API

Readability

RTCOOL

Feeds api

Boilerpipe

Goose

An overview of text extraction algorithms: http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/03/text-extraction.php

best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Nope. If you want access to the built-in one, you can file an enhancement request with the Apple [bug reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com). There are also third-party services like [Readability](http://www.readability.com/publishers/api) which, depending on the purpose of your app, you might be able to make use of.