# Obtaining the article contents of a webpage like Safari Reader

Tags: parsing, safari, html

Has anyone got any idea how one could get the article text of a webpage just like safari reader or evernote clearly does so that I can use the article text for some further work?

Comment: check this answer 
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303841/is-there-an-api-for-safari-reader>